# Is macchanger safe to use?

Tags: security, hardware

Has anyone used macchanger? Can it be recommended? Is it safe to use? Where can I find out more information about it? Is the code viewable somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

> Has anyone used macchanger, can it be recomended?

The answer to this is evidently that someone has used it. Otherwise it would probably not have been made. I've even used it myself for debugging.

> Is it safe to use?

Define safe. It will *probably* not brick your computer, and it will almost certainly not make the neighboring nuclear power plant melt down. It will probably not do any damage to your computer either. It may break your workplace terms.

> Where can i find out more information about it?

`man macchanger` provides the documentation you need. It's a rather simple tool.

> is the code viewable somewhere?

Yes.

`sudo apt source macchanger` will grab the source for you, and apply Ubuntu-specific patches, so you end up with the source that will build the actual package you install.